# When read csv file from flask it shows a TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'FileStorage'

Tags: python-3.x, csv, flask

When I am uploading a CSV file from flask frontend when writing file it shows me TypeError:bytes like object is required not 'FileStorage'.[image]

Here is my python function.

[image]